# i want display sum of column value group by column. How to display?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
  SELECT om.unitgroup unit, SUM (COUNT (od.tagno)) AS driftcount
    FROM oehistory od, oeunitmaster om
   WHERE     od.unitcode = om.unitcode
         AND od.status <> 'N'
         AND timestamp BETWEEN TO_DATE ('25-07-2018', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
                           AND TO_DATE ('26-07-2018', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
GROUP BY om.unitgroup
  HAVING COUNT (od.tagno) > 1
ORDER BY od.status ASC;

╔═════════╦════════════╗
║ unit    ║ DriftCount ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║  FR     ║          2 ║
║  FR     ║          4 ║
╚═════════╩════════════╝
```

i want display sum of diffcount group by unit.

How to display?

expected output is

```
╔════════╦═════════════════╗
║  unit  ║ totalDriftCount ║
╠════════╬═════════════════╣
║  FR    ║               6 ║
╚════════╩═════════════════╝
```

error is

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
>   00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: Check your `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: If you only need to get unit, why are you grouping by other columns?

Comment: removed other columns in group by, but still not getting result

Comment: Please post you actual query and the result you're getting now

Comment: select om.unitgroup unit, sum(count(od.tagno) )as DriftCount
            from oehistory od , oeunitmaster om
            where od.unitcode=om.unitcode
            and od.status<>'N' and timestamp between TO_DATE ('25-07-2018', 'dd-MM-yyyy') AND TO_DATE ('26-07-2018', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
            group by od.status,having count(od.tagno) >1
            order by  od.status asc;

Comment: error is ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: there's a comma before `having`... also, you group by a column, but extract a different one

Comment: group by om.unitgroup unit having count(od.tagno) >1

Comment: error is ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: Please edit the question with your actual code and the error you're getting.. Comments are not the right place for code. About the logics, if you want to get some help in understanding how to get the result you need, some sample data are needed

Answer (score 0):

If you order by some column, you need to include it into you `group by` clause.
So, if you need this ordering, you have to group:

```
SELECT om.unitgroup unit, SUM(od.tagno) as DriftSum,  COUNT(od.tagno) AS DriftCount
    FROM oehistory od, oeunitmaster om
   WHERE     od.unitcode = om.unitcode
         AND od.status <> 'N'
         AND timestamp BETWEEN TO_DATE('25-07-2018', 'dd-MM-yyyy') AND TO_DATE('26-07-2018', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
GROUP BY om.unitgroup, od.status
  HAVING COUNT(od.tagno) > 1
ORDER BY od.status ASC
```

This will give you as many rows as many values you have for `od.status`, for each value of `om.unitgroup`.

Differently, if you don't want rows splitted by status, you have to remove the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT om.unitgroup unit, SUM(od.tagno) as DriftSum,  COUNT(od.tagno) AS DriftCount
    FROM oehistory od, oeunitmaster om
   WHERE     od.unitcode = om.unitcode
         AND od.status <> 'N'
         AND timestamp BETWEEN TO_DATE('25-07-2018', 'dd-MM-yyyy') AND TO_DATE('26-07-2018', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
GROUP BY om.unitgroup
  HAVING COUNT(od.tagno) > 1
```

Comment: error:ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 8

Comment: I kept your mistake; SUM or COUNT, not both... you only have to understand which one you need. just edited

Comment: sum of tagno not possible because it's type is varchar.